# python 3d A* pathfinging infinite loop

Tags: python-3.x, path-finding, a-star

I am trying to adapt an application I found [here](https://medium.com/@nicholas.w.swift/easy-a-star-pathfinding-7e6689c7f7b2), I imagined that I just had to add an axis. The problem is that the script seems like it is stuck. Can someone tell me what I did wrong and how I can use A* with a 3d matrix (i j k)?

this is the portion of the A* function I changed

```
for new_position in [(0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1), (0, 1, 0), (0, 1, 1), (1, 0, 0), (1, 0, 1), (1, 1, 0), (1, 1, 1)]: # Adjacent squares, (-1, -1), (-1, 1), (1, -1), (1, 1)]: # Adjacent squares removed to ignor diagonal movement

    # Get node position
    node_position = (current_node.position[0] + new_position[0], current_node.position[1] + new_position[1], current_node.position[2] + new_position[2])

    # Make sure within range
    if node_position[0] > (len(maze) - 1) or node_position[0] < 0 or node_position[1] > (len(maze[len(maze)-1]) -1) or node_position[1] < 0 or node_position[2] > (len(maze) - 1) or node_position[2] < 0 or node_position[2] > (len(maze[len(maze)-1]) -1):
        continue

    # Make sure walkable terrain
    if maze[node_position[0]][node_position[1]][node_position[2]] != 0:
        continue
```

it was originally:

```
for new_position in [(0, -1), (0, 1), (-1, 0), (1, 0), (-1, -1), (-1, 1), (1, -1), (1, 1)]: # Adjacent squares

    # Get node position
    node_position = (current_node.position[0] + new_position[0], current_node.position[1] + new_position[1])

    # Make sure within range
    if node_position[0] > (len(maze) - 1) or node_position[0] < 0 or node_position[1] > (len(maze[len(maze)-1]) -1) or node_position[1] < 0:
        continue

    # Make sure walkable terrain
    if maze[node_position[0]][node_position[1]] != 0:
        continue
```

this is the whole script with my alterations:

```
import numpy as np

class Node():
    """A node class for A* Pathfinding"""

    def __init__(self, parent=None, position=None):
        self.parent = parent
        self.position = position

        self.g = 0
        self.h = 0
        self.f = 0

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.position == other.position


def astar(maze, start, end):
    """Returns a list of tuples as a path from the given start to the given end in the given maze"""

    # Create start and end node
    start_node = Node(None, start)
    start_node.g = start_node.h = start_node.f = 0
    end_node = Node(None, end)
    end_node.g = end_node.h = end_node.f = 0

    # Initialize both open and closed list
    open_list = []
    closed_list = []

    # Add the start node
    open_list.append(start_node)

    # Loop until you find the end
    while len(open_list) > 0:
        # Get the current node
        current_node = open_list[0]
        current_index = 0
        for index, item in enumerate(open_list):
            if item.f < current_node.f:
                current_node = item
                current_index = index

        # Pop current off open list, add to closed list
        open_list.pop(current_index)
        closed_list.append(current_node)

        # Found the goal
        if current_node == end_node:
            path = []
            current = current_node
            while current is not None:
                path.append(current.position)
                current = current.parent
            return path[::-1] # Return reversed path

        # Generate children
        children = []

        for new_position in [(0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1), (0, 1, 0), (0, 1, 1), (1, 0, 0), (1, 0, 1), (1, 1, 0), (1, 1, 1)]: # Adjacent squares, (-1, -1), (-1, 1), (1, -1), (1, 1)]: # Adjacent squares removed to ignor diagonal movement

            # Get node position
            node_position = (current_node.position[0] + new_position[0], current_node.position[1] + new_position[1], current_node.position[2] + new_position[2])

            # Make sure within range
            if node_position[0] > (len(maze) - 1) or node_position[0] < 0 or node_position[1] > (len(maze[len(maze)-1]) -1) or node_position[1] < 0 or node_position[2] > (len(maze) - 1) or node_position[2] < 0 or node_position[2] > (len(maze[len(maze)-1]) -1):
                continue

            # Make sure walkable terrain
            if maze[node_position[0]][node_position[1]][node_position[2]] != 0:
                continue

            # Create new node
            new_node = Node(current_node, node_position)

            # Append
            children.append(new_node)

        # Loop through children
        for child in children:

            # Child is on the closed list
            for closed_child in closed_list:
                if child == closed_child:
                    continue

            # Create the f, g, and h values
            child.g = current_node.g + 1
            child.h = ((child.position[0] - end_node.position[0]) ** 2) + ((child.position[1] - end_node.position[1]) ** 2)+((child.position[2] - end_node.position[2]) ** 2)
            child.f = child.g + child.h

            # Child is already in the open list
            for open_node in open_list:
                if child == open_node and child.g > open_node.g:
                    continue

            # Add the child to the open list
            open_list.append(child)


def main():


    maze = np.zeros((12,12,12))
    start = (10, 9, 9)
    end = (1, 1, 1)

    path = astar(maze, start, end)
    print(path)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A* can work with any number of dimensions; it's a graph traversal algorithm, and no matter how many dimensions your problem space has, connecting one position to another still produces a graph.

You have two problems with generating new nodes, however.

- You included `(0, 0, 0)` in the list, so *no change*. You keep putting the current position back into the queue for consideration. That’s just busy work, because the current position is already in the closed list.
- You never *subtract* from any of your coordinates, you only *add*. So your `x`, `y` and `z` values can only ever go *up*. If reaching your goal requires a path *around* an obstacle, then you have a problem here because all your version can ever do is move in one direction along any given axis.

In a 3 by 3 by 3 3D matrix, with the current position in the middle, there are 3 times 3 times 3 minus 1 == 26 positions you can reach with a single step. Your code reaches just 7 of those, plus one that stays put.

If you extract your tuples in the `for new_position in [...]` list into a separate variable and add some newlines, and re-arrange them a bit to group them by how many `1`s you have in the tuple, you get the following definition. I renamed this to `deltas`, because it's not a new position, it's the *change* relative to the old position, or *delta*. I re-arranged your tuples to make it easier to group them logically:

```
deltas = [
    (0, 0, 0),  # no change, 
    (0, 0, 1), (0, 1, 0), (1, 0, 0), # add to a single axis
    (0, 1, 1), (1, 0, 1), (1, 1, 0), # add to two axes
    (1, 1, 1)  # move in all 3 directions at once.
]

for delta in deltas:
    # ...
```

You want to drop the first one (`(0, 0, 0)`), and you need to add `-1` versions of the other variants. You need 26 different tuples, but writing those by hand gets to be cumbersome, really fast. You can use [`itertools.product()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) to generate these, instead:

```
from itertools import product

# combinations of -1, 0 and 1, filtering out the (0, 0, 0) case:
deltas = [d for d in product((-1, 0, 1), repeat=3) if any(d)]
```

Now, your comment next to the loop says:

```
# Adjacent squares removed to ignor diagonal movement
```

It's not entirely clear what you mean by this, because your original list of deltas includes diagonals (`(0, 1, 1)` moves both in the `y` and `z` directions, and you have tuples combining movement in the `x` plus `y` and the `x` plus `z` axes), and even one that moves diagonal by incrementing all 3 axes. If you only wanted to move *up*, *down*, *left*, *right*, *forward*, and *backward*, you want to restrict movement to a single axis at a time, and `deltas` should be:

```
# movement without diagonals
deltas = [
    (1, 0, 0), (-1, 0, 0),  # only x
    (0, 1, 0), (0, -1, 0),  # only y
    (0, 0, 1), (0, 0, -1),  # only z
]
```

Personally, I'd move the whole business of generating new positions to a separate method *on the `Node` class*:

```
def possible_moves(self, map):
    x, y, z = self.x, self.y, self.z
    for dx, dy, dz in DELTAS:
        newx, newy, newz = x + dx, y + dy, z + dz
        try:
            if maze[newx][newy][newz] != 0:
                yield Node(self, (newx, newy, newz))
        except IndexError:
            # not inside the maze anymore, ignore
            pass
```

This method assumes that there is a `DELTAS` global variable that defines the possible moves, and is a generator; each time `yield` is reached a new `Node()` instance is returned to whatever is using this as an iterator (like a `for` loop would).

Then just use that method instead of the `children = []` list you filled with the `for new_position in ...:` loop, so directly in the part that uses the original `children` list:

```
# Loop through children
for child in current_node.possible_moves(map):

    # Child is on the closed list
    for closed_child in closed_list:
        if child == closed_child:
            continue

    # etc.
```